# unixODBC SQLExecute() error

Tags: c++, postgresql, odbc, unixodbc

*Sometimes* I get quite strange error message from SQLExecute() during INSERT. Have no idea how I can deal with this, other queries are ok.

**Log**

```
[ODBC][67383][1485443238.457802][SQLPrepare.c][196]
    Entry:
        Statement = 0x101022600
        SQL = [INSERT INTO Core_Message(channel_id, date, member_id, reply_id) VALUES(25, '2017-01-26 18:07:18', 4, NULL) 
][length = 109 (SQL_NTS)]
[ODBC][67383][1485443238.457893][SQLPrepare.c][377]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][67383][1485443238.458014][SQLExecute.c][187]
        Entry:
            Statement = 0x101022600
[ODBC][67383][1485443238.458189][SQLExecute.c][357]
        Exit:[SQL_ERROR]
        DIAG [HY000] no error information;
Error while preparing parameters

[ODBC][67383][1485443238.458543][SQLFreeHandle.c][381]
        Entry:
        Handle Type = 3
        Input Handle = 0x101022600
[ODBC][67383][1485443238.458670][SQLFreeHandle.c][494]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
```

**Code**

```
    SQLLEN length(0);
    if (!isSuccess(SQLPrepare(_statement, (unsigned char *)query.c_str(), SQL_NTS))) {
        _status = StatementStatus::Fault;

        return false;
    }

    for (std::size_t i=0; i<reference_vector.size(); i++) {
        length = reference_vector.at(i).get().length();
        if (!isSuccess(SQLBindParameter(_statement, i + 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_BINARY, SQL_VARBINARY, reference_vector.at(i).get().length(), 0, (char *)reference_vector.at(i).get().c_str(), (SQLLEN)reference_vector.at(i).get().length(), &length))) {
            _status = StatementStatus::Fault;

            return false;
        }
    }

    if (!isSuccess(SQLExecute(_statement))) {
        _status = StatementStatus::Fault;

        return false;
    }
```

Tricky block with SQLBindParameter() event don't used in runtime.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please ad a complete self-contained program that exhibits the problem. There are too many possibilities of things that could be wrong in the code you are *not* showing. Specifically, we cannot see the parameter values you use.